# change img src using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="s4-titlelogo">
 <a href="/sites/mysite">
<img name="onetidHeadbnnr0" id="ctl00_onetidHeadbnnr2" style="border-right-width: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px;" alt="bobpub" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" complete="complete"/>
</a>
</div>
```

If the src attribute of the img is blank.gif, then i want to set the src attribute to my icon url "/_layouts/images/myicon.gif". I need to reference the img as this $('.s4-titlelogo img').

SO FAR:

```
iconurl = $('.s4-titlelogo a>img').attr("src");
            if (iconurl == ""/_layouts/images/blank.gif")
            {

            }
```

Comment: Do you want to change the src under specific circumstances?

Comment: I think you should add several img tags (one for each image you're going to need) and then swap them (make one invisible and the right one visible).

Comment: Do you have more than one element with the class "s4-titlelogo"?

Comment: just one s4-titlelogo

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> If the src attribute of the img is blank.gif...

```
if($('.s4-titlelogo img').attr('src') === '/_layouts/images/blank.gif')
```

> ...then i want to set the src attribute to my icon url.

```
$('.s4-titlelogo img').attr('src', '/_layouts/images/myicon.gif');
```

Edit: Three downvotes instantly? Uh... why?

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2MhJ/) example to prove that this works.

Comment: Curious to know why so many downvotes as well. Answer seems legit to me.

Comment: This works only if there's **one** element with the class "s4-titlelogo" (which the OP did just point out is true), as well as only one `<img>` descendent. Otherwise, the `if` statement checks against the first `.s4-titlelogo` found, but the `attr` setter sets all occurrences.

Comment: @Ian: this answer is based on what is given in the original question, nothing more. Nowhere is it mentioned that there are multiple images or multiple `.s4-titlelogo` dividers.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly It's common sense that there can be multiple elements with the same class. I was just pointing out how your code **only** works properly **if** there is only one `.s4-titlelogo` element...didn't say it was wrong or right. And since the OP said there's only one, then it's "right". At the same time, you shouldn't need to use jQuery twice to select the same thing - the getter for `.attr` applies to different elements (only the first) than the setter (all)

Answer (score 3):

Just do this...

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/FW4kj/

```
$(function(){

    //Get the element
    elem = $('.s4-titlelogo img');

    //If 'src' attribute contains 'blank.gif'
    if (elem.prop('src').indexOf('blank.gif') > 0)
        //Replace 'src' attribute with 'myicon.gif'
        elem.prop('src', '/_layouts/images/myicon.gif');

    //Alert new 'src' attribute just to verify
    alert('New image url is: ' + elem.prop('src'));

});
```